# Best Practice for deploying ADF pipelines

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am brand new to ADF and am creating my very first data factory.  I am using the UI option (if anyone can point me to any documents for using code I'd be most grateful).

I will have 3 different environments - dev/test/prod.  Each of these have got slightly different configs (yes I know!).  So my datasets and linked services will need to change for each environment.  What is the best way to do this?  How would you approach this?
(p.s: We also have BitBucket and Jenkins/Octopus for CI/CD, so ideally would like to create scripts to automate this if possible.)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create data factory using code. You can find code with detailed information [here](http://azure-docs/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net.md%20at%20master%20%C2%B7%20MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs%20%C2%B7%20GitHub)

There are 2 approach to deploy ADF pipeline.

1. ARM template
2. Custom approach (Json files, via REST API) - With this approach, we can fully automate CI/CD process as collaboration branch will be our source for deployment. This is the reason why the approach is also known as (direct) deployment from code (JSON files).

Refer this [blog](https://sqlplayer.net/2021/01/two-methods-of-deployment-azure-data-factory/) by Kamil Nowinski

Scope of the question is broad. But, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLf3nAiGG3Q) by Mohamed Radwan practically shows how you can deploy and manage 3 different environments i.e. ADF-DEV, ADF-PROD and ADF-UAT.